# How can I sweep duty cycle of a pulse train in PSPICE?

Tags: pspice

I have found some solution in LTspice but Im wondering if anybody could achieve to sweep duty cycle of a fixed freq. pulse in PSpice.

Is that possible?

I tried the following but it didnt work:

[image]

Comment: Build a pulse width modulator and run a ramp signal into it.

Comment: Sure thing. Ypu can set your on-time to {ton} and do a parametric step or sweep.

Comment: @winny I use VPULSE pulse generator in Orcad's Pspice. There are only parameters: V1 V2 TD TR TF PER PW. I just started to use Pspice. Could you please write what you suggest as an answer with a simple example. Thanks in advance

Comment: I normally use LTspice, but your PW should have the same effect. Set it to a variable.

Comment: If you want a *continuous* sweep with a simple voltage source, you can't, but you can use the `.STEP` directive on the `Ton` parameter, as @winny mentions. If you decide to use two sources and a comparator (of your choice), then you can use JohnD's suggestion for a continuous sweep.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Please see my edit. I tried comparator way but couldnt make it work. Please help with an answer if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a comparator. I would have answered in the comments section, but I feel it may not be enough, so here's as example made in LTspice:

[image: example]

What you are using is a VCVS (voltage controlled voltage source), which simply outputs the difference between its non-inverting input and its inverting one, multiplied by the amount of gain.

You need to use a comparator, or something with a comparator's properties. I used LTspice's Schmitt A-device, which has complementary ouputs (you can ignore the negated one) and is set with a `1mV` positive hysteresis, in order to directly compare with an VCVS (`E1` in the schematic) transformed to behave similarly to a comparator.

Note that, while I seem to recall (from some 20 years ago) that PSpice has some default, ideal comparator (that you can use instead of my `A1`), and that it should have some form of the original Berkeley SPICE's `table()` function, I don't know how to implement it, so it's up to you.

`V1` acts as a variable duty-cycle generator (it is a simple voltage going from `5%` of the ramp's amplitude, to `95%` -- it could have been a `PWL` just as well), while `V2` is the ramp generator. Notice I didn't use extreme values like `1ps` for the timings, or so, but simply a more relaxed `0.1%` of the total period, which works just fine while also not uselessly encumbering the simulation.